# multi-lines pattern matching

Tags: regex, bash

I have some files with content like this:

file1:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
123
```

file2:

```
AAA
BBB
123
```

I want to echo the filename only if the first 3 lines are letters, or "file1" in the samples above.
Im merging the 3 lines into one and comparing it to my regex [A-Z], but could not get it to match for some reason

my script:

```
file=file1    
if [[ $(head -3 $file|tr -d '\n'|sed 's/\r//g') == [A-Z] ]]; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

I ran it with bash -x, this is the output

```
+ file=file1
++ head -3 file1
++ tr -d '\n'
++ sed 's/\r//g'
+ [[ ASMUTCEDD == [A-Z] ]]
+exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed:

- You can use `grep` to check that the input matches only `[A-Z]` characters (or indeed Bash's built-in regex matching, as @Barmar pointed out)
- You can use the pipeline directly in the `if` statement, without `[[ ... ]]`

Like this:

```
file=file1    
if head -n 3 "$file" | tr -d '\n\r' | grep -qE '^[A-Z]+$'; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

Comment: Why use `grep` when `bash` has built-in regular expression support?

Comment: @Barmar I can write this easily and with confidence without having to check some critical details of the built-in regex syntax, such as how to quote properly (if at all), and if `+` actually works. In short, it's easier. Also, to use `[[ ... ]]`, you need a sub-shell. I'm not saying this is the best solution. This is easy.

Answer (score 1):

To do regular expression matching you have to use `=~`, not `==`. And the regular expression should be `^[A-Z]*$`. Your regular expression matches if there's a letter anywhere in the string, not just if the string is entirely letters.

```
if [[ $(head -3 $file|tr -d '\n\r') =~ ^[A-Z]*$ ]]; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-ins and [character classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) for this problem:-

```
#!/bin/bash

file="file1"
C=0
flag=0

while read line
do
        (( ++C ))

        [ $C -eq 4 ] && break;

        [[ "$line" =~ '[^[:alpha:]]' ]] && flag=1


done < "$file"

[ $flag -eq 0 ] && echo "$file"
```